# Is there a program that demonstrates overall fitness will increase in a population overtime?

Tags: genetics, evolution, population-genetics, evolutionary-game-theory

Of course this will not always be the case with environmental factors, but generally speaking. I'm searching for a program that shows evolution works from a statistical standpoint.

Comment: Which theory of evolution requires fitness to increase in populations over time to "work"?

Comment: Look into Richard Lenski's long-term experimental evolution work. In addition to more than 60,000 generations of E. coli evolution with numerous fitness published fitness studies, he has published some work trying to study evolution in "digital organisms."

Comment: One can readily design such an evolutionary simulation. There are many such programs, many of them [designed for educational purposes](https://www.biologysimulations.com/evolutionsimulation). Others are used to explore the theoretical effect of varying certain parameters including formalized environmental factors. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Fisher wrote on this (hypersphere). Then it was improved by Kimura. Now, as the other commenters mention, there are modern much better ways of simulating this.